# php how to show message before process is end

Tags: php

PHP how to display a message "newsletter sent, can close page" before sending function is complete?Thank you.

```
function myfun(){
    if(!ob_start("ob_gzhandler"))
        ob_start();
    $mail_id = $id;
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/newsletter/".$template);// include a newsletter template
    $htmltext = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    // close current session
    if (session_id()) 
        session_write_close();

    sleep(2);
    sendmail($htmltext); //sendo more then 2000 whith PHPmailer
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just print the message in the last line of the function? It will be the last statement to execute and hence, function has reached its completion.

Comment: Can you post the function call code?

Comment: Start the sending of the mails in an independent process. That causes the user hasn't to wait for this to end and - even more important - he cannot interrupt this process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For Halloei How do you start sending in a separate process?

Answer (score 0):

hey You can simple echo the code of an alert script to display your message. As I am doing below:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Your Message");
</script>';
```

You can even wrap this in a function provide your message as a parameter and call it any where you want to display your message.